# Rails ancestry gem + has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many, ancestry

I have 2 models: Post and Category

Category has_many Posts,

Post belongs_to Category,

Category model uses [ancestry gem](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry),

the goal is to get all posts that belongs_to the given category and to all its ancestors. Should I  simply use a loop for this or there is some smarter way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by `ancestors` here?

Comment: Updated, I meant ancestry gem (link above).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this to get the posts that belong the given `category` or one of its ancestors:

```
Post.where(:category_id => category.path_ids)
```

Comment: Didn't know that Rails is so smart that can just accept array there.

Answer (score 1):

The [`ancestry gem`](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry#arrangement) passes nested hash objects when you use it, so you can select a master `node` and then use the hash object as a way to iterate through & get all of its ancestors:

```
#controller
@category = Category.find params[:id]

#view
render partial: "category", locals: { category: @category }

#partial
<ol class="categories">
    <% category.each do |category, sub_item| %>
        <li>
            <%= category.name %>
            <% if category.has_children? %>
            <%= render partial: "category", locals: { category: category.children } %>
            <% end %>
        </li>
    <% end %>
</ol>
```